# Form submits even though it is not passing validation through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm making a simple form and have made a function for each field to validate. But when I test the form via live server, the form submits even if the fields don't validate. Each function seems to work as intended aside from that.

```js
function validateForm () { 

  var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phonenumber').value;


  function firstNameValid () {

    if (firstName == "") {
      console.log("First name empty")
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    };

  };

  firstNameValid();


  function phoneValid () {

    if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber == "" || phoneNumber.length < 10) {
      console.log("Phone number must be defined and not exceed 10 characters")
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };

  phoneValid();


  result = firstNameValid() && phoneValid();

  };
```

```html
 <body>

    <form name="registration" action="page2.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="GET">

    <ul>

    <li>
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>       
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" onsubmit="return firstNameValid()"><br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" onsubmit="return phoneValid()">    
    </li>

    </ul>

    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

    </form>

    <script src="app.js"> </script>
</body>
```

Comment: try to use e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning the result variable

```
result = firstNameValid() && phoneValid();
return result;
```

Comment: I have tried this and the form is still submitting for whatever reason. I am using five functions as opposed to the two in this example but same structure nontheless.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the result.

```js
function validateForm() { 

  var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phonenumber').value;


  function firstNameValid () {

    if (firstName == "") {
      console.log("First name empty")
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    };

  };




  function phoneValid () {

    if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber == "" || phoneNumber.length < 10) {
      console.log("Phone number must be defined and not exceed 10 characters")
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };


  return firstNameValid() && phoneValid();
 

  };
```

```html
 <body>

    <form name="registration" action="page2.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="GET">

    <ul>

    <li>
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>       
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber">    
    </li>

    </ul>

    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

    </form>

</body>
```